# opening the validated pdf file does not show text

Tags: pdf

[this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10EOaaJk6WZqLe2hQjgcs5Zm9KqOzdKr7) pdf file has been validated by online pdf tools, I have also checked it as per pdf reference book by Adobe, but when I open it, there is no text in this file while there should be a line. Could someone please get me the problem in this file? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what validation tools you were using, but they are wrong.

If I open the file in Acrobat, and then close it, Acrobat offers to 'save the changes'. This is a clear sign that there's something wrong with the file which Acrobat has silently fixed.

Opening with Ghostscript displays the expected text, but gives 1 warning and 1 error :

```
GPL Ghostscript GIT PRERELEASE 9.24 (2018-03-21)
Copyright (C) 2018 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
   **** Warning:  length of some xref entries is not equal to 20 bytes.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
   **** Error: stream operator isn't terminated by valid EOL.
               Output may be incorrect.
Loading NimbusSans-Regular font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Regular... 7545788 5687824 4474868 3160873 3 done.
>>showpage, press <return> to continue<<
```

So there are two problems, one of which is rather common. The PDF Reference makes it clear that xref entries must be exactly 20 bytes. See page 94 of the 1.7 PDF Reference Manual :

> Following this line are the cross-reference entries themselves, one
>   per line. Each entry is exactly 20 bytes long, including the
>   end-of-line marker.

...

> The byte offset is a 10-digit number, padded with leading zeros if
>   necessary, giving the number of bytes from the beginning of the file
>   to the beginning of the object. It is separated from the generation
>   number by a single space. The generation number is a 5-digit number,
>   also padded with leading zeros if necessary. Following the generation
>   number is a single space, the keyword n, and a 2-character end-of-line
>   sequence. If the file’s end-of-line marker is a single character
>   (either a carriage return or a line feed), it is preceded by a single
>   space; if the marker is 2 characters (both a carriage return and a
>   line feed), it is not preceded by a space. Thus, the overall length of
>   the entry is always exactly 20 bytes.

The first entry in the xref table of your PDF file is 19 bytes long (I haven't checked the rest).

The second error is, I believe, the one causing the text display problem; the Contents stream looks like this:

stream BT /F1 24 Tf 100 700 Td (abcdef gh ijklmnop) Tj ET endstream

If you look at that with a binary or hex editor you will see that the stream keyword is followed by a space (0x20). If you read page 60 of the PDF Reference Manual it says:

> The keyword stream that follows the stream dictionary should be
>   followed by an end-of-line marker consisting of either a carriage
>   return and a line feed or just a line feed, and not by a carriage
>   return alone.

If I modify the space character following the 'stream' keyword to be a line feed (0x0A) then Acrobat will display the line of text too. It will still offer to save the changes though, because the xref table entries are still wrong.

Comment: *"The first entry in the xref table of your PDF file is 19 bytes long (I haven't checked the rest)"* - the same issue with all of them.

Comment: *"The keyword stream that follows..."* - an even better reference is "The keyword **stream** that follows the stream dictionary shall be followed by an end-of-line marker" as this expresses an requirement ("shall"), not a mere recommendation ("should"); ISO 32000-1 section 7.3.8 – Stream Objects.